# Geo IP Apache module reliability

Tags: apache-2.2, geolocation, geoip

I'm looking for some simple way to determine the country a user is viewing the site from, it's only a branding issue and not a legality issue, so a few false positives won't matter so much.

Apaches mod_geoip seems to be just what I'm looking for but there's no indication of how accurate it is.

Does anyone have any hard figures on accuracy?
e.g.

- How many users out of a 1000 were accurately located at the country level?
- How many down to a City level?
- Any particular areas of decreased reliability (South America, Australasia)?

Alternatively, is there another fast, reliable Geolocation solution I could use? (3rd party web services aren't really an option, too much overhead to be worth it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_geoip is just a way to interface with maxminds databases.

http://www.maxmind.com/

they are the ones who actually provide the databases of ip -> country/city.

a good place to start checking their accuracy would be http://www.maxmind.com/app/city_accuracy.

note, the city based database is not free. the country based one does come in a free version.

enjoy.

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for, found this on their site: http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry States 99.5% accuracy for the free version. And given that they're not making money off it I would imagine that's not too much of an exageration. Thanks.